# ngClass with multiple expressions with a runtime class

Tags: angular, ng-class

Child Component Template (child-component):

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'default': !inputCssClass, inputCssClass: inputCssClass }"></div>

<div [ngClass]="{ 'default': !inputCssClass, {{inputCssClass}}: inputCssClass }"></div>

<div [ngClass]="{ 'default': !inputCssClass, '{{inputCssClass}}': inputCssClass }"></div>
```

All the above give me parser errors.
Idea behind the above code is:
        inputCssClass is an Input Property of the Component.

Parent component can define its own class and pass it as input.
for example:

parent component can define its class as:

```
div.error{
       color:red;
   }
div.success {
    color:green;
}
```

And instead of having to define all the classes in the child component, the parent components can define their own and pass the class name to the child component.

```
<child-component inputCssClass="'error'"></child-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`<child-component inputCssClass="error"></child-component>`
```

or

```
`<child-component [inputCssClass]="'error'"></child-component>`
```

in child template :

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'default': !inputCssClass, 'error': inputCssClass === 'error', 'success': inputCssClass === 'success' }"></div>
```

Comment: thanks!. What abt on the ChildComponent Template? None of the 3 syntaxes seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data to Child component you should use `@Input` decorator in Child component ts file and change from `inputCssClass="'error'"` to `[inputCssClass]="'error"`. So in your case it would look like:

**Parent HTML file**

```
<child-component [inputCssClass]="'error'"></child-component>
```

**Child Component ts file**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component', 
    templateUrl: './child-component.html
})
export class ChildComponent {
   constructor() { }
   @Input() inputCssClass;
}
```

Comment: thanks!. What abt on the ChildComponent Template? None of the 3 syntaxes seem to work.

Comment: Hmm, do you need to add n-classes or it's predefined number ?

Comment: If it's predefined number of possible classes you could just use `[ngClass]=" inputCssClass ? inputCssClass : 'default' "`; which means if inputCssClass is an `true` value it will assign inputCssClass value otherwise 'default' class will be assign.